# Pyglet image drawing issue

Tags: python, pyglet

Whenever I try to draw an image onto the screen with pyglet, this happens:
(The original image is just a red square.)

[image: issue]

This started happening when I got my new pc, both with new programs, such as this one, and programs that I wrote on my old pc. I have made sure my graphics drivers are up to date.
Pyglet 1.5.7, Python 3.8.6.
Since this happens with every program I write, I don't think it is an issue with the code, but here is the code for this particular instance:

```py
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import key

class main(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(main, self).__init__(500, 500, fullscreen = False)
        self.alive = 1
        self.batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
        self.sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.image.load('red.png'), batch = self.batch)
    def on_close(self):
        self.alive = 0
    def render(self):
        self.clear()
        
        self.batch.draw()
        
        self.flip()
    def run(self):
        while self.alive == 1:
            self.render()
    
window = main()
window.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled my graphics drivers, making sure to check "Delete the driver software for this device," rebooted my pc, and reinstalled the drivers. That fixed my issue.